# YouTube video in UIScrollView not getting touches/playing

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, youtube

I have a setup where I have a scrollview that displays a large image that the user can zoom in on and scroll and there are certain zones on the image that have a `UIWebView` drawn on them with a YouTube video in them.

I cannot for the life of me get the youtube video to play from touching on it. I can get the video to play if I find the play button in the view and then send the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` control event to it but that isn't ideal as then I cant use the scrubber, play/pause/fullscreen functionality.

I know that a `UIWebView` shouldn't be used in a `UIScrollView` but I cannot think of another way to get the youtube videos in there.

Currently setup like

```
- UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
    - UIView
        - UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate> (multiple)
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: can u please show code what you are trying ,from that we will give you proper answer.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, I have managed to sort it out, it was an issue with userInteractionEnabled being set to NO and a conflict with the UITapGestureRecognizer (needed to clear its delegate). All seems to be good now

Answer (score 0):

All sorted, was a mixture of UITapGestureRecognizer conflicts and userInteractionEnabled being set to NO